How do I construct Radix-4 CT butterfly using Radix-2 CT butterfly?
I am trying to construct Radix-4 CT butterfly using Radix-2 CT butterfly for NTT.
I know it must be a two-layer structure with each layer containing two Radix-2 CT butterflies.
But I am not sure how the two layers should be connected and what the twiddle factors for each butterly should be.

Walk through the Radix-2 code for a transform of length 4 in the debugger and you will quickly see what the twiddle factors are. Hint: Radix-2 is 1,-1. So what might Radix 4 be? Sadly Radix-4 algorithm detail is missing on Wiki. This looks OK though Radix-4 FFT
